# Is it possible to interrupt parsing large xml file in the middle with lxml target parsing interface?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am getting information from a large xml file and I am using python with [lxml target parsing interface](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#the-target-parser-interface) to do it. I would like the possibility to set a limit after which parsing stops. Here is some code:

Parser target code:

```
class TitleTarget(object):
    def __init__(self,  limit=None):
        self.limit = limit
        self.counter = 0

    def start(self, tag, attrib):
        if self.limit and self.counter > self.limit:
            #### BREAK HERE ####
            return False
        #doProcessing(attrib)
        self.counter = self.counter + 1

    def end(self, tag):
        pass

    def data(self, data):
        pass

def close(self):
    pass
```

Code initiating the parsing:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(target = TitleTarget(limit)) 
etree.parse(file, parser)
```

I know that the processing goes to the "BREAK HERE" -line, but I haven't found any method to stop the parsing. I have tried returning `True, False, [], and raising Error`, none seem to work. It always processes until the file ends.

Is there a way to stop processing bu using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `etree.parse(file, parser)`, you can loop over the lines in `file` and call `parser.feed` on each line. This gives you control over when to break out of the loop.

Now you can just set a `self.done=True` in the target, and test for `target.done` in the feed loop:

---

```
import lxml.etree as ET
class HaltingTarget(object):
    def __init__(self, limit=None):
        self.done=False
        self.limit=limit
        self.counter=0
        self.result=[]
    def start(self, tag, attrib):
        if self.limit and self.counter>self.limit:
            self.done=True
            return
        if attrib:
            self.result.append(attrib)
        self.counter+=1
    def end(self, tag):
        pass
    def data(self, data):
        pass
    def comment(self, text):
        pass
    def close(self):
        return
def halt_parser():
    content='''\
        <node1>
          <Title a1="x1"> My Title </Title>
          <node2 a1="x2"> ... </node2>
          <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
        </node1>
        '''
    target=HaltingTarget()
    parser=ET.XMLParser(target=target)
    for line in content.splitlines():
        parser.feed(line.strip())
        if target.done: break
    # We can't call parser.close() since the XML we've fed it is probably 
    # incomplete. We don't plan to use `parser` anymore, so delete it.
    del parser
    print(target.result)
    # [{'a1': u'x1'}, {'a1': u'x2'}, {'a1': u'x1'}]
```